# Add a shared folder to google drive using a share link

Tags: google-drive-api

Newest Edit:

So here is what i want to accomplish:

1) User installs my application on his computer.
2) User grants my app access to his drive.
3) My app shares a folder from my drive with the user.

The problem in accomplishing part 3) is that my app actually needs write access to my drive, so it can share my folder with the current user. But for security reasons there is no way i can grant my app write acces to my drive.

Now im asking for a possibility to perform part 3) without granting my app write access for my drive.

---

I would like my installed application to add a shared folder to a users google drive account by only using a share link i generated manually for a folder i've created in my drive. Is it possible to accomplish this using google drive API?

Edit: What i actually want to do is to create a folder in the users drive and link this folder to a folder in my drive, so the user can access the files stored in my drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shortcut to another's shared directory? Google Drive doesn't support it but, you can create an application to handle it.

1. [Create a shortcut](https://developers.google.com/drive/integrate-create?hl=en) to your application.
2. Add the the link you want your user to be redirected as a [custom property](https://developers.google.com/drive/properties) to the shortcut file.
3. When user opens the file from Drive and being redirected to your app, read the custom property you stored.
4. Redirect user to the the location on the retrieved custom property.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is actually doesnt solve my problem. I gues i have not made myself sufficiently clear, so i've edited my privious posting.

Comment: My suggestion solves your problem only if the folder is publicly available with a link. If not and you can't programmatically share your folder with the user (that requires a write permission, which you're not willing to give), it's not possible.